# Dynamic ng-model binding ng-repeat loop in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a following collection of fields.

```
$scope.fields = ['name','postcode','phone'];
```

I need to have input controls dynamically generated as many as the fields above. So a fixed version of below

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.field" /> <!-- .field isn't resolving -->
    </div>
</div>
```

would hopefully generate something like below...

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div><input class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" /></div>
    <div><input class="form-control" ng-model="user.postcode" /></div>
    <div><input class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" /></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: where is `user` coming from? `field` is not a property of `user` in the example you are giving so it won't work..

Comment: @deolectrix Angular will create necessary missing properties if they are requested.

Comment: @dfsq thanks, my mistake, you learn something new every day...;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access variable object property:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="user[field]" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/fkCYr4k0RwizxsOS9HhC?p=preview

Comment: Bracket notation is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I guess it should be ng-model="user['{{field}}']" no?

Comment: @jme11 No, inside of expression it would be literally property of the `user` with the key `'{{field}}'` and without quotes `user[{{field}}]` it would be exception. There is a demo in the answer, just try yourself ans check results.

Comment: Cool, didn't notice the demo before, but it makes sense.